# How do I float parent & children, while keeping children in one line?

Tags: html, css, css-float

How do I wrap the floating divs of unknown sizes (children) with a border (parent), while keeping the children in the same line.

The problem is that unless the parent div is set to `width: 100%;`, children tend to collapse one beneath the other.

[image]

UPDATE: While posting code, I figured it out, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26Wwq/).

My code had extra `<div>` wrappers around children. I either had to remove them or set them to `display: inline;`.

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="parent">
        <div>
            <div class="child"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="child"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="child"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Thanks for other great tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't change the children divs to `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`, they will be vertically stacked.  If the children are `float`ed , their size will not push the boundaries of the parent.  If you use `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`, the children will be inline as long as the parent can be wide enough to fit them all and they will stretch the parent.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MPCsD/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set at least child's or parent's width as fixed. Maybe you can measure them with java scripts.